# Why does a very simple edit mode bmesh operation crash Blender?

Tags: scripting, add-on, bmesh

I'm trying to create an addon that runs in edit mode, using bmesh to transform the various elements. I'm getting a crash with the most basic example I can come up with:

```py
import bmesh
import bpy


bl_info = {
    "name": "Crash",
    "blender": (3, 3, 1),
    "category": "Object",
}

class Crash(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Crash Blender."""
    bl_idname = "mesh.crash"
    bl_label = "Crash"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}

    def execute(self, context):
        edit_mode_mesh = bpy.context.object.data
        mesh = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(edit_mode_mesh)
        bmesh.update_edit_mesh(edit_mode_mesh)
        mesh.free()
        return {"FINISHED"}


def menu_func(self, context):
    self.layout.operator(Crash.bl_idname)


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Crash)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.append(menu_func)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Crash)
    bpy.types.VIEW3D_MT_edit_mesh.remove(menu_func)
```

To replicate:

- Save this file as `addon.py`.
- Install `addon.py` as an addon and enable it.
- Select the default cube and switch into edit mode.
- From Edit -> Menu Search search for "Crash" and hit Enter. Nothing will happen yet.
- Repeat the above step. Blender should crash.

The crash still happens if I remove the calls to `bmesh.update_edit_mesh` and `mesh.free`.

Any ideas as to what's going wrong?

Comment: Hello ! In this case I think `mesh.free()` is automatically called when the function returns so I think it's not mandatory. Removing only this line prevents the crash on my end. See the explanation on https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.free As I understand the main use of this method is to prevent further unwanted access down the line, not to prevent a memory leak.

Comment: Thanks, that also fixes the crash for me. If you want to make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: The bmesh you get from from_edit_mesh() must never be freed: https://developer.blender.org/T39121#210495

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think `mesh.free()` is automatically called when the `execute` method returns so I think it's not mandatory.

Removing only `mesh.free()` looks like it prevents the crash on my end. There is an explanation on https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.free

> The BMesh is freed automatically, typically when the script finishes
> executing. However in some cases its hard to predict when this will be
> and its useful to explicitly free the data.

As I understand the main use of this method is to prevent further unwanted access down the line, not to prevent a memory leak. So if this is the last thing your script does, you can go ahead and skip calling it altogether since it will be dealt with automatically.